# Are there any legal implications if you proxy Oracle's Maven proxy via an artifact repository manager for internal development?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I would like to understand, if there are any legal implications, if you use an artifact repository manager such as Nexus/Artifactory/Archiva, to proxy [Oracle's Maven repository](http://maven.oracle.com/). I'm asking because you need to have an OTN account in order to access this repository and accept their [Terms of Use](https://www.oracle.com/us/legal/terms/index.html). If we are using licensed libraries, for which we are paying, does this fall under section 2. (c) and what does that mean? Does redistributing include internal redistribution for developers and servers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: @chepner: You are right. If there is a better place for this question, perhaps the moderators could move it there?